# How to encode values that appear less than N times with special category ("Other", for instance)?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 12 columns of type `object`, and I want to encode those values in columns that appear less than `N` times (say, 1000) into special cateogry ("Other"). I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67791379/12081269) but I have 12 features to consider and I'd like to have something more universal. In addition, I tried doing something like this:

```
for col in train_data.select_dtypes('object'):
    train_data.select_dtypes('object')[col] = np.where(train_data.select_dtypes('object')[col]. \ 
           value_counts() < 1000, "Other", train_data.select_dtypes('object')[col].value_counts())
```

But got an error on sizes:

```
ValueError: Length of values (8) does not match length of index (251396)
```

How does universal solution look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Disclaimer: since previously I only used R language, I try to avoid the usage of for-loops and that is why this solution was not obvious for me

I found for myself the following solution for my specific problem. It is based on selecting column values which length is less than `N` with a usage of `.loc`, `groupby` and `transform` methods.

```
preprocessed_cols = []

for col in train_data.select_dtypes('object'):
    
    if any(train_data.select_dtypes('object'). \
        groupby(col)[col].transform('size')<1000) == True:
        
        preprocessed_cols.append(col)
    
    train_data.select_dtypes('object').loc[train_data.select_dtypes('object'). \
                                           groupby(col)[col].\
                                           transform('size')<1000, col] = 'Other'
    
print('There are {} features that needed replacement'.format(len(preprocessed_cols)))
```